# armature breaking mesh/pose and rest mode are different despite no changes made

Tags: mesh, rigging, armature, vertex-groups, pose-mode

I'm hoping I can get some help with a problem I'm having using an IK rig on a metahuman model I'm working on. It seems that adding the armature causes the rig to split at certain points like the shoulders, hips etc (pictured for reference).

[image: object/pose mode]
[image: edit mode]

I'm bit of a noob when it comes to rigging and while I've searched for some solutions I've had no joy thus far so thought I'd ask outright. I've tried resetting scale/position of the rig but that's not fixed it. Even though I haven't altered the armature at all since parenting the mesh to it, the "pose" and "rest" positions are ever so slightly different.

Could this be a vertex group problem with weighting? From issues I've read on here before it seems it may be but the particular problems other users were having don't seem to apply, or if they do I'm too ignorant to know how. If you could help me identify what's going wrong here I'd be really grateful!

blend file for your info: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1MWTwtXbtD4kFAn466Fi9tNl2jW81WrJc?usp=sharing

Cheers, Dom

Answer (score 0):

The edges are ripped, you need to select all and press <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge by Distance* to fix that. Then parent the object to the armature again with the *With Automatic Weights* option and it will work fine:

[image]

Comment: Well that was painfully simple! I think where I went wrong in trying this before was not unparenting the mesh before doing this. Thanks so much for the speedy, clear reply!

Comment: you don't even need to unparent, just merge by distance then parent again